# How do I simply import a folder in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-import

Running python code with python 2.7.16, I have an issue when I try to import some files from a folder that is at the root of the python code.

I think it might be a path issue but when I manually add the folder to the path I get other similar errors from the other files. So not very useful.

My code is very simple

```
from core import network
```

The python code is located at the same place as the `core` folder

The directory structure is :

directory 1:

- code.py
- core folder :

  -- network.py

Error is :

```
from core import config
ImportError: No module named core
```

What do you think ?

Comment: Share your project directory structure

Comment: create a file `__init__.py` inside core folder and then try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add `__init__.py` to core folder and the import should work.

In python2 there should be a `__init__.py` file in a directory.

You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@ramrajchandradevan/python-init-py-modular-imports-81b746e58aae)